# Disable the other attributes checked when a radio ckecked is chosen

Tags: jquery

When I mark an input radio attribute, and then change it is still marked as "checked".
I made several attempts but could not, I need to clear each other when one is selected.

**JQuery :**

```
$('.service-inputs .radio-container').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
});
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1or4e712/)**.

Answer (score 2):

That exactely what radio button are made for, you have radios with same name `service` that mean you can check just one in same time, without using any JS code and other will disabled by default, check example bellow.

Hope this hleps.

---

```css
.service-inputs .radio-container{
  background: red;
  padding: 50px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-inputs">
  <a href="#" class="radio-container">
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="webdesign" checked>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="radio-container">
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="Cirtual Collective">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="radio-container">
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="Branding">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="radio-container">
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="Marketing">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="radio-container">
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="Product Sourcing">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="radio-container">
    <input type="radio" name="service" value="Consulting">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong, that's not what I want. look the fiddle. I need to enable only one, not all.

Comment: What you mean by enable?

Comment: when click in the <a> find the input radio and enable but the others input dont disable.
The final result is
`checked="checked">` for all

Comment: That not happen in my example, you can see that when one is enable the others inputs are not enable and not checked, that happen in your fiddle because you prevent the Default action of radio that will disable others check **[updated fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1or4e712/2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the checked attributes on the siblings:

```
$('.radio-container').click( function(event){
    $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
    $(this).siblings().find('input:radio').attr('checked', false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/90Lmgdxs/

Comment: As per the original request, when a radio button is selected it receives and attribute, checked='checked'. This was maintained on the element even when another radio button was selected. My example above clears the attribute from the all elements aside from the selected one.